# the number of all orders of elements in HS (Higman-Sims group) with GAP

Tags: group-theory, gap

I want to calculate the number of all orders of elements in HS (Higman-Sims sporadic simple group). Is there any way of doing this with MAGMA or GAP? How I can determine orders of elements of a group with `CharacterTable` in GAP?

Comment: Please reformulate "number of all orders" - it's not clear what you're asking (is it $\mid\{n \mid \exists g \in G : Order(g)=n \}\mid$? And yes, character table will answer this kind of questions.

Comment: Alternatively use the function ConjugacyClasses, and look at the sizes of the classes and the orders of their representative elements.

Comment: @DerekHolt: indeed, I mean that for this particular group it's easier to fetch the precomputed character table from the library and then get the data about conjugacy classes and orders from it. For a general case, one should use  `ConjugacyClasses` in the first instance.

Comment: You may also receive this information from the **Atlas of Finite Groups**, the relevant page for $HS$ is [here](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/spor/HS/#ccls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, having a group in GAP, information about the orders of its elements could be derived from its conjugacy classes and orders of their representatives, for example:

```
gap> G:=Group([ (3,7,5)(4,8,6), (1,2,6)(3,4,8) ]);
Group([ (3,7,5)(4,8,6), (1,2,6)(3,4,8) ])
gap> List(ConjugacyClasses(G),Size);
[ 1, 56, 24, 24, 21, 42 ]
gap> List(ConjugacyClasses(G),c -> Order(Representative(c)));
[ 1, 3, 7, 7, 2, 4 ]
```

Clearly, for a large group having this information precomputed would be extremely useful, and due to the [Atlas of Finite Group Representations](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/), such opportunity exists. For example, you may see the information about conjugacy classes [in the Atlas page on $HS$ here](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/spor/HS/#ccls) without using any computational algebra system.

The [GAP Character Table Library](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Thomas.Breuer/ctbllib/) derives some data from Atlas, and you may find information about conjugacy classes of $HS$ stored in its character table in the following way:

```
gap> t:=CharacterTable("HS");
CharacterTable( "HS" )
gap> SizesConjugacyClasses(t);
[ 1, 5775, 15400, 123200, 11550, 173250, 693000, 88704, 147840, 1774080, 
  1232000, 1848000, 6336000, 2772000, 2772000, 2772000, 2217600, 2217600, 
  4032000, 4032000, 3696000, 2956800, 2217600, 2217600 ]
gap> OrdersClassRepresentatives(t);
[ 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 15, 
  20, 20 ]
gap> ClassNames(t);
[ "1a", "2a", "2b", "3a", "4a", "4b", "4c", "5a", "5b", "5c", "6a", "6b", 
  "7a", "8a", "8b", "8c", "10a", "10b", "11a", "11b", "12a", "15a", "20a", 
  "20b" ]
```